# Как выключить изменение позиции камеры в Google Maps SDK iOS[closed]

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Привет!

Как выключить изменение позиции камеры?

Пытаюсь создать mapView с маркерами. Хочу чтобы маркеры(didTapMarker) можно было нажимать, а изменять положение камеры нельзя. Пробовал задать `mapView.userInteractionEnabled = NO`, но в этом случае не срабатывает метод `didTapMarker`

**UPDATE**: Решилось простым `[mapView.settings setScrollGestures:NO];`

Comment: а метода типа mapView.scrollEnabled = NO у Google Maps нет

Comment: Вопрос закрыт: `[mapView.settings setScrollGestures:NO];`